# Appending to List On certain Condition

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program, when certain condition is met the value is appended to list.

Ex:

lets say the last limit is 1000
start the count from 1
if count value is a multiple of 50, append it to a list

So the list should have numbers, 50,100,150,200...and so on..I am stuck at the third step, how would i let python know that the value is a multiple of 50

Thanks For Helping Me.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You are asking for very basic programming knowledge here, and we can help you much better when you have specific code.

Comment: Something like `range(50, 1001, 50)`?

Comment: yeah i know thats a very basic question, m new to python, i can well count the number, but i am confused how to let it know that its a multiple of 50.

i am trying the for loop.
for i in 1000: and then i am lost..

Comment: @larsmans thanks that helped. appreciated.. M sorry for the basic question, m very new to python.

Answer (score 2):

use `%` operator , it returns the remainder. So if a number is a multiple of 50 then it's remainder will be 0, except the case that the number itself is 0.(i.e 0 divided by 50 will result in 0 as remainder)

```
>>> lis=[]
>>> for x in range(1,1001):
      if x%50==0:        
        lis.append(x)
>>> lis
[50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 850, 900, 950, 1000]
```

Answer (score 1):

If an int `i` is a multiple of 50, then by definition it will have zero remainder when divided by 50 - Python, like most programming languages, has a [modulo operator](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) to check exactly that - "is i a multiple of 50?" is spelled:

```
if i % 50 != 0:
   # i is a multiple of 50
```

Or equivalently:

```
if not i % 50:
   # i is a multiple of 50
```

Which of these you use depends on whether you think of this as "the remainder is zero" or as "there is no remainder" - but they will always give the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>>a = [i for i in range(1,1001) if i%50==0]
>>>print a
```

or

```
>>>a = [i for i in range(1,1001) if not i%50]
>>>print a
```